# Trying to remember a possible Sci Fi Anime/Movie

Tags: voltage-fighter-gowcaizer

I had seen this anime/movie when I was pretty young, so it's probably from the late 80's early 90's. It was also dubbed in English.

I vaguely remember the scene, it was with a man and a dark wolf like creature. I assume the wolf had just finished doing a killing/deed. The man congratulates her(the wolf) saying something like, "You did good work, you can have the rest of the day off." As to which she replies with glee, then turning into a woman. I think she had dark hair, perhaps purple?

The scene then cuts to her blissfully taking a shower. When she finishes, she walks into a hotel room where there's a robot. (For some reason the only comparison I can think of is Wheatley from Portal2.) To which when the robot sees her, "malfunctions" as a response to her being only in a towel.

I can also remember that the hotel overlooks a city scape, though that's all.

Comment: Seems an interesting anime. Do you know what kind of genre is it? Are they the main characters, or only the girl? Also, maybe the background setting of the anime? I'm thinking "Wolf's Rain", but certainly not sure about the robot.

Comment: I imagine the genre to at least be sci-fi and fantasy, due to the robot and the woman turning into the wolf-like creature. From what I remember, the robot can also talk, as she talks to it in a familiar manner. It's also possible the woman is a main character, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find the answer!

It's [Choujin Gakuen Gowcaizer](http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?id=1560)

It seems I mistook the wolf and the dark haired woman for the same person.
They are actually two different people.

Also, the film seems to have been released in the late 90's, not late 80's early 90's as I had previously thought.